# Make rotary knob control

Tags: c#, controls

I need to do a rotary knob control, or use one that works. I download one from that web: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/desaijm/knobcontrolusingwindowsforms11182005004925am/knobcontrolusingwindowsforms.aspx but it doesn't work as I want.

I need that this knob control can make a complete circle when I move it. At the moment when you go to the max values, if you pass this value the button go automaticaly to the other value (that is 0).

All i want to do is to increment the knob rotary value all the times without a max value and not to restart to 0 when it pass the max value.

I post the code where the value change happens, but I was working on it for 3 hours and I don't know how to change... There are also two variables thar are maximum and minimum that have the max and min values of the knob.

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //--------------------------------------
        //  Following Handles Knob Rotating     
        //--------------------------------------
        if (this.isKnobRotating == true)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            int posVal = this.getValueFromPosition(p);
            Value = posVal;
        }       
    }
```

Any idea to do that or any C# control that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: UI Design Note: Unless this is for a touch screen, please don't. They are a royal pain to use with a mouse. Please consider a slider.

Comment: Yes, is for a touch screen

Comment: It is a very miserable UI gadget.  The days that computer screens still had to resemble the instruments they replaced are over and done with, WIMP has been around long enough.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my own solution, hope this help other people!

```
if (this.isKnobRotating == true)
        {
            lastValue = Value;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            int posVal = this.getValueFromPosition(p);
            Value = posVal;
            if ((lastValue >= Maximum + radiusLeft - 1) && Value == 0)
            {
                numRounds++;
            }
            else if (lastValue <= Minimum && (Value == Maximum + radiusLeft - 1))
            {
                numRounds--;
            }
            finalValue = (Maximum + radiusLeft) * numRounds;
            result = finalValue + Value;
        }
```